# Is there a way to display text or a dialogue only if the user came from a certain page/site?

Tags: javascript, html

So I want my site to display an alert if the user has come from reddit.com/r/subredditname (or any page within that subreddit), and also to display a different alert if they have come from example.site.com (or any page within). Is there a way to accomplish this or is that not something that js/html can do?